# Stream PC audio to Skype

Tags: windows, audio, skype

Is there any simple solution to stream the **output** system/application sound to Skype, as the microphone input?
For example - I want my contact to hear the YouTube video being played at the same time.

Also, if I could control which applications or processes being streamed to Skype individual it would be even better.

I'm on PC - Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit

Thanks

Comment: What OS? If you're on a Mac, you can use [Soundflower](https://github.com/Cycling74/Soundflower) (though it doesn't give you control over which apps get redirected).

Comment: I'm on PC - Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit. Also edited the post

Comment: @matan129 Like VAC, but free: http://jackaudio.org

Comment: If you want it cheap then check if you have the stereo downmix option in your sound configuration available (google it). If not then Virtual Audio Cable is the best solution here. And yes it costs money, but it also is a pretty complex and high class solution and it costs the developer money for having his audio driver licensed by Microsoft. Why would anyone spend money after also doing all the work just so that cheapskates could profit from it for free?

Comment: @Zerobinary99 Calm down. Let's not start flinging insults around here.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Oh I'm not agitated, don't worry. Just pointing out that he probably won't find a free solution since this solution will require a driver that needs to be signed and that costs money.

Comment: @Zerobinary99 While it doesn't let you pick and choose apps, Soundflower is free. And I'm willing to bet there's a free solution for Linux distros (or at least that it wouldn't cost any money to make one).

Comment: @BlacklightShining But didn't you say that Soundflower is for Mac only? This guy is running Windows 7, so this wouldn't apply. And yes I agree, there is probably a free Linux alternative, but does Skype even support Linux natively? I guess it would run in Wine though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Portable software tool to pipe sound output to microphone input](http://superuser.com/q/346593/150988), [How to play MP3 files into the microphone input](http://superuser.com/q/190093/150988), [What's the reason for “Stereo Mix” option being missing?](http://superuser.com/q/299082/150988), [How to record sound directly from output?](http://superuser.com/q/299082/150988), and [Direct sound from speakers (output) to mic (input)](http://superuser.com/q/218488/150988).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look: http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm

> Virtual Audio Cable software allows you to transfer audio (wave)
>   streams between applications and/or devices.

Comment: @matan129 Just cause it costs money doesn't make it a bad answer.

Comment: @duDE - it kind of does, because I need to be able to use this software.

Comment: @duDE Doesn't Stack Exchange discourage product recommendations?