# How to use audio autput and microphone input as a single Input?

Tags: windows, audio, music, audio-streaming, audio-output

Im was searching for a programm, that combines audio output and microphone Input as a single input. I am trying to live stream and I have to choose an Input, but I want the viewers to hear the audio output and Input at the same time. Please help. I am using Windows xp 32 Bit SP3.

Comment: Have you looked at the **Related** questions (on the right side of the page; scroll down a little)?  For example, [How to play MP3 files into the microphone input](https://superuser.com/q/190093/354511),  [Is it possible to pipe multiple audio sources into a single virtual “microphone” input?](https://superuser.com/q/510798/354511),  [How to Record both Mic and Speaker Audio in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/472045/354511), and [How do I record sounds directly from my sound card?](https://superuser.com/q/274120/354511)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the windows Sound properties switch to the "recording" tab, and then right-click the blank area and ensure that "show disabled" and "show disconnected" are both enabled (checked), you should see an option for "stereo mix." Enable it, and then select that as your recording input for your streaming software.

"Stereo mix" is the aggregated audio output from all shared sources. Older versions of windows may have called it "what you hear" if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Doing what you are proposing a budge. It might work, but not that well.

If you are livestreaming are you using any software for that? For example, in OBS you can add both your desktop audio and your microphone as inputs and even control their levels separately. Any livestreaming software (OBS, Wirecast, vMix, SLOB, etc.) can do that.

1. make a scene
2. click the little "+" icon at the bottom
3. add an audio source - choose "desktop audio"
4. add audio source - choose your mic

Also Windows XP was already very outdated when you wrote the question. You're better of using Linux. Or grab a Win10 copy, their cheap and there are also ways to get a key without paying, but you shouldn't do that...